# Find all three distinct natural numbers such that sum of their reciprocals is 1.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find all  three distinct natural numbers such that sum of their reciprocals  is 1.

$1/2+1/3+1/6=1$ is one such solution.

Comment: Are they distinct natural numbers, or distinct collections of natural numbers? Because if it is all distinct collections of natural numbers, then $\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{1}{4} = 1$ also works. But, ordering the summands differently would not generate an additional collection.

Comment: You should say "Find all $3$-member sets of  natural numbers whose reciprocals add to $1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's all there is.

Note that the smallest can't be 1 (no room for the other two reciprocals), and it must therefore be 2 (otherwise the sum would be at most $\frac13+\frac14+\frac15<1$), so you want two distinct natural numbers $a,b>2$ such that $\frac1a+\frac1b=\frac12$, i.e., $ab = 2(a+b)$.  But this is $(a-2)(b-2)=4$ and the only way we can only factor $4$ as the product of two distinct natural numbers is $1\times 4$.

Comment: Or, by continuing with the method that shows that one of them must be $2$, if $1/a+1/b=1/2$ then neither $a$ nor $b$ is $1$ or $2,$ but one of $a,b$ is $3$, else $1/a+1/b\leq 1/4+1/5<1/2.$ So one of them is $3$ and the third number is $(1-1/2-1/3)^{-1}=6.$..........+1